# String to date time in informatica

Tags: sql, informatica

I am preparing an Informatica mapping

Source:- Oracle
Target :- Teradata

There are 2 columns in the mapping
Source column name : INX_DATE(string) and UPX_DATE (string)
Target column name : INX_DATE(date/time) and UPX_DATE (date/time)

Source column contains something like this

UPX_Date:-08-FEB-16 12.00.23.826315000 AM +00:00
INX_Date:- 08-FEB-16 12.00.23.826315000 AM EUROPE/BELGRADE

Now the issue is how will I get this to my target which is date/time
and should be MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS

Comment: Hey Guys Please help me here

Answer (score 1):

You can substring the first 31 characters and then convert it to date.

```
TO_DATE(SUBSTR(INX_DATE,1,31),'DD-MON-YY HH12:MI:SS.NS AM')
```

As far as I know, PowerCenter Date/Time cannot store the time zone information. If you need that, you may need to adjust the time separately.

Comment: Thanks for taking out time for giving an Answer.